# Divide table raw into chunks in Postgres with st_dwithin limit

Tags: postgresql, recursion, postgis, recursive-query

I got a table with linestrings that I want to divide into chunks that have a list of id not higher than provided number for each and store only lines that are within certain distance.

For example, I got a table with 14 rows

```
create table lines ( id integer primary key, geom geometry(linestring) );
insert into lines (id, geom) values ( 1, 'LINESTRING(0 0, 0 1)');
insert into lines (id, geom) values ( 2, 'LINESTRING(0 1, 1 1)');
insert into lines (id, geom) values ( 3, 'LINESTRING(1 1, 1 2)');
insert into lines (id, geom) values ( 4, 'LINESTRING(1 2, 2 2)');
insert into lines (id, geom) values ( 11, 'LINESTRING(2 2, 2 3)');
insert into lines (id, geom) values ( 12, 'LINESTRING(2 3, 3 3)');
insert into lines (id, geom) values ( 13, 'LINESTRING(3 3, 3 4)');
insert into lines (id, geom) values ( 14, 'LINESTRING(3 4, 4 4)');
create index lines_gix on lines using gist(geom);
```

I want to split it into chunks with 3 ids for each chunk with lines that are within 2 meters from each other or the first one.

The result I am trying to get from this example is:

```
| Chunk No.|  Id chunk list |
|----------|----------------|
|     1    |    1, 2, 3     |
|     2    |    4, 5, 6     |
|     3    |    7, 8, 9     |
|     4    |   10, 11, 12   |
|     5    |      13, 14    |
```

I tried to use [st_clusterwithin](https://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.2/ST_ClusterWithin.html) but when lines are close to each other it will return all of them not split into chunks.

I also tried to use some with recursive magic like the one from the answer provided by [Paul Ramsey](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/457/paul-ramsey) [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/94203/grouping-connected-linestrings-in-postgis). But I don't know how to modify the query to return limited grouped id list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if it is the best possible answer so if anyone has a better method or know how to improve provided answer feel free to update it. With a little modification of Paul answer, I've managed to create following queries that are doing what I asked for.

```
    -- Create function for easier interaction
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION find_connected(integer, double precision, integer, integer[])
  returns integer[] AS
$$
WITH RECURSIVE lines_r AS -- Recursive allow to use the same query on the output - is like continues append to result and use it inside a query
    (SELECT ARRAY[id] AS idlist,
            geom, id
           FROM lines
           WHERE id = $1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT array_append(lines_r.idlist, lines.id) AS idlist, -- append id list to array
           lines.geom                             AS geom,   -- keep geometry
           lines.id                               AS id -- keep source table id
    FROM (SELECT * FROM lines WHERE NOT $4 @> array[id]) lines, lines_r -- from source table and recursive table
    WHERE ST_DWITHIN(lines.geom, lines_r.geom, $2) -- where lines are within 2 meters
      AND NOT lines_r.idlist @> ARRAY[lines.id] -- recursive id list array not contain lines array
     AND array_length(idlist, 1) <= $3
    )
SELECT idlist
FROM lines_r WHERE array_length(idlist, 1) <= $3 ORDER BY array_length(idlist, 1) DESC LIMIT 1;
$$
LANGUAGE 'sql';

-- Create id chunks
WITH RECURSIVE groups_r AS (
    (SELECT find_connected(id, 2, 3, ARRAY[id]) AS idlist, find_connected(id, 2, 3, ARRAY[id]) AS grouplist, id
                             FROM lines WHERE id = 1)
    UNION ALL
    (SELECT array_cat(groups_r.idlist, find_connected(lines.id, 2, 3, groups_r.idlist)) AS idlist,
            find_connected(lines.id, 2, 3, groups_r.idlist)            AS grouplist,
            lines.id
     FROM lines,
          groups_r
     WHERE NOT groups_r.idlist @> ARRAY[lines.id]
     LIMIT 1))
SELECT 
--        (SELECT array_agg(DISTINCT x) FROM unnest(idlist) t (x))    idlist, -- left for better understanding what is happening
       row_number() OVER () chunk_id,
       (SELECT array_agg(DISTINCT x) FROM unnest(grouplist) t (x)) grouplist,
       id input_line_id
FROM groups_r;
```

The only problem is that performance is quite pure when the number of ids in the chunk increase. For a table with 300 rows and 20 ids per chunk, execution time is around 15 min, even with indexes on geometry and id columns.